# Макрос перенос столбца libreoffice basic

Tags: libre-office-calc

Имеется

```
Dim Doc as object
Dim sheet as object
Dim sheets as object
Doc=thiscomponent
Sheet=doc.sheets(0)
```

Как выделить целиком столбец, например с индексом 2 и вставить его в столбец с индексом 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенос столбца:

```
    Dim doc as object
    Dim sheet as object
    doc=thiscomponent
    sheet=doc.sheets(0)

    source = sheet.Columns(2)
    target = sheet.getCellByPosition(5, 0)
    ' или target = sheet.getCellRangeByName("F1")
    sheet.moveRange(target.CellAddress, source.RangeAddress)
```

Для простого копирования заменяем `moveRange` на `copyRange`.

Дополнительную информацию можно найти в [wiki](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Macros/Basic/Calc/Ranges#Working_with_ranges)